# efficiently convert leading zeroes in each row to numpy.nan in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
   thing1  thing2   num_col1    num_col2   num_col3    num_col4
    aaa     abc      0.0         99.76     101.1        111.2
    bbb     cde      11.3        109.76    201.1        121.2
    ccc     def      91.3        0.0       301.1        131.2
   .....
   .....
    aaa     efg      0.0         0.0       401.1        141.2
    bbb     fgh      41.3        299.76    0.0          151.2
    ccc     ghi      201.3       199.76    601.1        161.2
```

and I want to convert it to this:

```
   thing1  thing2   num_col1    num_col2   num_col3    num_col4
    aaa     abc      nan         99.76     101.1        111.2
    bbb     cde      11.3        109.76    201.1        121.2
    ccc     def      91.3        0.0       301.1        131.2
   .....
   .....
    aaa     efg      nan         nan       401.1        141.2
    bbb     fgh      41.3        299.76    0.0          151.2
    ccc     ghi      201.3       199.76    601.1        161.2
```

explanation: if, values of columns `num_col1`, `num_col2`, `num_col3` and `num_col4` start with 0, those 0s need to be converted to `numpy.nan` and any 0s in the middle of the columns shouldn't be touched. How do I do this as efficiently as possible (by using any builtin funcitons and not using python's loops etc,.)?

Comment: If "any 0s in the middle of the columns shouldn't be touched" why is the zero in row 3 of num_col2 changed to a nan?

Comment: that was a mistake from my side while creating the example. thanks for highlighting it @Bill. i am editing it now.

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala do you mean if the **rows** start with `0`, then all those `0` is `NaN`?

Comment: yes @QuangHoang, but 0s in b/w rows must not be converted to nans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the starting 0, it usually involves cumsum on the negate condition. Something like this:

```
mask = (df.filter(like='num_') # extract numeric data, modify if needed
          .ne(0)               # where the numbers are not 0
          .cumsum(axis=1)      # these shows the blocks of `0`  
          .eq(0)               # rows starting with zero 
       )
```

Then you would have the mask as:

```
   num_col1  num_col2  num_col3  num_col4
0      True     False     False     False
1     False     False     False     False
2     False     False     False     False
3     False     False     False     False
4     False     False     False     False
5      True      True     False     False
6     False     False     False     False
7     False     False     False     False
```

Finally, you can use `mask` to mask your data:

```
df[mask.columns] = df[mask.columns].mask(mask)
```

And you get (notice the `0` at line `5`, `num_col4`):

```
  thing1 thing2  num_col1  num_col2  num_col3  num_col4
0    aaa    abc       NaN     99.76     101.1     111.2
1    bbb    cde      11.3    109.76     201.1     121.2
2    ccc    def      91.3      0.00     301.1     131.2
3  .....   None       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
4  .....   None       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
5    aaa    efg       NaN       NaN     401.1       0.0
6    bbb    fgh      41.3    299.76       0.0     151.2
7    ccc    ghi     201.3    199.76     601.1     161.2
```

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, you can create a mask dataframe for `num_col` columns that is equal to zero and loop through the `num_col` columns to check if values between `num_col1` and the iterative `num_col` column are all True.

```py
cols = df.filter(like='num_col').columns
m = df[cols].eq(0)

for idx, col in enumerate(cols[1:]):
    m[col] = m[cols[:idx+2]].all(axis=1)

df[cols] = df[cols].mask(m, np.nan)
```

```
print(df)

  thing1 thing2  num_col1  num_col2  num_col3  num_col4
0    aaa    abc       NaN     99.76     101.1     111.2
1    bbb    cde      11.3    109.76     201.1     121.2
2    ccc    def      91.3      0.00     301.1     131.2
3    aaa    efg       NaN       NaN     401.1     141.2
4    bbb    fgh      41.3    299.76       0.0     151.2
5    ccc    ghi     201.3    199.76     601.1     161.2
```

If you also allow zero starts from right, you can try

```py
for idx, col in enumerate(cols[1:-1]):
    m[col] = (m[cols[:idx+2]].all(axis=1)) | (m[cols[idx+1:]].all(axis=1))
```

Comment: Why replace values greater than zero but less than one?

Comment: @Bill Because negative values start with `-`.

Comment: Yeah it's confusing but I think by "if, values of columns ... start with 0" they mean "replace the values in consecutive columns which are equal to zero from left to right starting with the first"

Comment: @Bill Understand now, updated the answer.